# Change String Indices to integer

Tags: python

I met this kind of error described as:

```
 File "/Users/thienhua/Desktop/usingnow/coding/sachml/Ch13/dtree.py", line 150, in printTree
    self.printTree([*tree][0][item], name + "\t")
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Where the error code lines are:

```
def printTree(self,tree,name):
        if type(tree) == dict:
            #print (name, tree.keys()[0])
            print (name, [*tree][0])
            for item in [*tree][0]:
                print (name, item)
                self.printTree([*tree][0][item], name + "\t")
        else:
            print (name, "\t->\t", tree)
```

Please help me fix this error. Here's the full code: [https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~marslast/Code/Ch13/dtree.py](https://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/%7Emarslast/Code/Ch13/dtree.py)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're trying to extract items from `[*tree][0]` twice.  You do `for item in [*tree][0]`, which iterates over all the items in that list, but then you use one of the items to try to look up that item in the same list with `[*tree][0][item]`.  That doesn't look right no matter what is in `item`, but I figure it is a string, which is why you get the error you're getting.  @adirabargil's answer gives you what I was going to suggest that you do instead.  I bet that gets you going.

Comment: What is `[*tree]` doing?  Can anyone explain it?  I've never seen that construct used before.  Obviously it does something valid, as the use of it in the OPs code doesn't seem to lead to an error.  I'm really curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to print the tree item just print it instead of trying to get it from the list.. python for loops are "for each" like...

```
self.printTree(item, name + "\t")
```

Alternatively, to demonstrate what the problem is you could iterate trough indexes:

```
for item in range(len([*tree][0])):
    #... rest of code
    self.printTree([*tree][0] [item], name + "\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is error mostly raise when we try to access list item using string than index number
For example if list having ["hii","hello","bye"] and this list's element can be called by index number but if we insert string in the place of index this type of error occurs